# Opening files in Python

Tags: python, file-io

I am getting a weird error when I try to open a file in my python program even though they are in the same directory.  Here is my code:

```
def main():
#filename = input("Enter the name of the file of grades: ")

file = open("g.py", "r")
for line in file:
    points = 0

    array = line.split()

    if array[1] == 'A':
        points = array[2] * 4
    elif array[1] == 'B':
        points = array[2] * 3
    elif array[1] == 'C':
        points = array[2] * 2
    elif array[1] == 'D':
        points = array[2] * 1

    totalpoints += points
    totalpointspossible += array[2]*4

gpa = (totalpoints/totalpointspossible)*4
print("The GPA is ", gpa)

file.close()

main()
```

and this is the error I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "yotam2.py", line 51, in <module>
main()
File "yotam2.py", line 28, in main
file = open(g.py, "r")
NameError: global name 'g' is not defined
```

I am not quite sure why it is saying g is not defined, even though it is in the same directory as my python file.

Comment: You may want to fix the whitespace in your code. And it looks like you have some undefined variables as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`g.py` should be a string:

```
file = open("g.py", "r")
```

Also, `array` is a list of strings. Multiplying strings by integers just duplicates them:

```
>>> "1" * 4
"1111"
```

You have to convert `array` (which isn't an array, by the way) into a list of numbers:

```
array = [int(n) for n in line.split()]
```

Comment: @bagelboy: Probably a `TypeError` near `totalpoints += points`?

Comment: @bagelboy: Your code and the error message don't match up. Are you editing the same file?

Comment: What do you mean by "don't match up"

Comment: @bagelboy: The error message points to a line of code that doesn't exist in your file: `open(g.py, "r")`. You already changed that.

Comment: yeah haha that is why I posted this on SO. It doesn't make sense to me.  I save it and run it in the shell and it gives me that error

Comment: @bagelboy: Are you editing `yotam2.py`? Delete any `.pyc` files in that folder and see if that helps.

Comment: I am editing yotam2.py and when I do "ls -a" in the directory, the four items that pop up are ".", "..", "g.py", and "yotam2.py" so there aren't any .pyc

Comment: "python yotam2.py" in an Ubuntu 12.10 terminal

Comment: @bagelboy: Are you *completely* positive that you're editing the same Python file (I've caught myself editing a different file with the same name many times)? You don't seem to be saving to the same file.

Comment: oops... that is embarrassing.  Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to enclose g.py in quotes.

The interpreter thinks g is a variable you are referencing rather than a filename you intend it to reference.

Answer (score 0):

`g.py` must be  replaced by `"g.py"` 
and `totalpoints` must be initialized